# Remotely connect to computer where I don't have admin access on

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, remote-desktop

I have a Windows XP computer, PC1, where I have no admin access. I am only a non-admin user. I want to remotely control PC1 from PC2 (Windows Vista, I am admin here). I need to make PC1 a server and PC2 the controller.

Obviously, I cannot use RDP because I am not admin. Is it still possible to enable remote login? Is there any *legal* tool to bypass admin and remotely access PC1 from PC2?

I'd prefer a portable/USB app to do this job because the admin of PC1 has blocked installation of software as well. TeamViewer Portable did not work because it is detected as malware by the anti virus software of PC1.

Comment: looks like UltraVNC is a solution. Will try and get back. http://www.uvnc.com/

Comment: what kind of ports need to be open on the server machine (ie pc1) for another computer to remotely control pc1 ? Is there any other thing one should keep in mind to do the remote controlling ?

Comment: VNC uses TCP\5900

Comment: Friendly warning: Please stop posting the link to your question on others' posts as comments, just to draw attention. This is quite rude. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the PC is logged in to a user account you can access occasionally, you can run [Real VNC Server](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/winvnc.html) in usermode. it does not use the MS authentication so there is no requirement for admin, beyond those that you the actions you take in XP require.

VNC authentication is weak and its traffic is unencrypted though, so you only want to use it between PCs on the same LAN. It is not safe to use over the internet unless you tunnel it via ssh or another tunneling encryption protocol.

Another option to try is [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/),  which does not require installation.

Comment: There is no portable version of VNC server or player. The files on the website require installation and the admin has blocked installation. Is it possible to install the files on a windows vista machine, copy installed files onto xp machine and run it xp ?

http://www.realvnc.com/download/get/1277/

Comment: The security is a concern, but not a big one. Can i use the wifi of my place to  do these remote logins ? or maybe connect both systems using lan cable ? I am not a tech person and i have never tried this before. So, please bear with my silly questions.

Comment: last time I looked real had a standalone executable download, but yes, VNC usually stands on its own, so try copying over the executables. look at TightVNC as well. as for security, as long as you are not connecting across the internet, you are fine to use VNC over your wifi, as long as you use WPA2. if you have unencrypted wifi however, it would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to conntrol a computers by connecting it to the controller by lan/ethernet a cable ? As an aside, how would unencrypted wifi be dangerous ?

Comment: yes, you could use a wired network to use VNC. the reason it would be bad to use unencrypted wifi, is that anyone who walks onto your property could connect to your wireless lan, and start controlling your server.